# Gallery Selection Working on Local but Not on Server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am referencing the gallery selector options that auto cycle in the relative content. This site is built in full HTML hard code so feel free to view source.

Everything is completely operational on local side. As soon as I upload to godaddy and test, the functionality is not working: https://www.steam-green.com/gallery.html

Here is what is not working:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse latest--project" id="navbarfiltr">
                    <ul class="simplefilter">
                        <li class="active" data-filter="*">All</li>
                        <li data-filter=".carpet-cleaning">Carpet & Rug Cleaning</li>                       
                        <li data-filter=".upholstery-cleaning">Upholstery Cleaning</li>
                        <li data-filter=".tile-and-grout">Tile & Grout</li>                         
                        <li data-filter=".hardwoods">Hardwoods</li> 
                        <br><br>    
                        <li data-filter=".water-damage-restoration">Water Damage Restoration</li>       
                        <li data-filter=".mold">Mold Removal</li>
                        <li data-filter=".rug">Area Rug</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Updated the piece of code that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing you are using isotope jquery library.
I saw your custom.js and I don't see where you are initilizing this plugin for that specific menu nor your html.

Please refer again to documentation https://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Its possible that you didn't update your custom.js file in production, please check.

Comment: My last resort was just to re-upload the entire site, but you have hit it right on the head! Thank you for this. What lead you to these resolution steps?

Comment: I checked your code in website url that you provided. I checked your js code and I saw your custom.js have initialization of all plugins that you require and other custom code. I didn't see the initialization for this plugin so I refer to docs if you would initialize using other methods. I didn't see that.